# Fit classifier with more data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am currently using [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) to create and fit a SVC classifier. To do this, I wrote the following code:

```
clf = SVC(probability=True).fit(X_labeled, Y_labeled)
```

I then use an active learning technique to get more data to improve the classifier's performance. To train the classifier on the new data, can I do this:

```
clf.fit(newData, newY)
```

or do I need to do this:

```
clf.fit(newData+X_labeled, newY+Y_labeled) #pseudocode
```

Comment: Yes there is a possibility without having to pass your old data again. It's called online learning.

Comment: I believe that the dupe should address your questions. Best of luck.

Comment: From the scikit-learn docs: [Strategies to scale computationally](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning)